# C# Telegram-API WTelegramClient Как программно нажать кнопку в сообщении от Телеграм-Бота?

Tags: c#, telegram

Разрабатываемая программа общается с Телеграм-Ботом. Боту посылается текстовое сообщение. Бот отвечает на сообщение. Ответ содержит 3 кнопки. Задача: Как нажать на кнопку программно?
Создаем Телеграм-клиента

```
_client = new WTelegram.Client(Config):
_user = await _client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
```

Декларируем функцию для получения обновлений от Телеграм

```
_client.Update += _client_Update;
```

Находим бота

```
var contacts = await _client.Contacts_Search("@Search_bot", 20);
contacts.users.TryGetValue(1911124859, out peerBot));
```

Отправляем запрос (сообщение) к Боту

```
var message = await _client.SendMessageAsync(peerBot, "REQUEST");
```

Получаем ответ

```
var differenceMessages = await _client.Updates_GetDifference(state.pts, state.date, state.qts);
```

Разбираем ответ

```
TL.Message tLMessage = null;
if (differenceMessages != null)
{
    if(differenceMessages.NewMessages != null)
    {
        foreach (var difference in differenceMessages.NewMessages)
        {
            tLMessage = difference as TL.Message;
            if (tLMessage != null) Log("Сообщение: " + tLMessage.message);
            if(tLMessage != null && tLMessage.peer_id.ID == peerBot.ID )
            {
                if (!(tLMessage.reply_markup is ReplyMarkup replyMarkup)) continue;
                TL.ReplyInlineMarkup replyInlineMarkup = (ReplyInlineMarkup)replyMarkup;
                if (replyInlineMarkup.rows[2].buttons[0].Text == "Check texn on Button")
                {
                    ***//TODO Как нажать на эту кнопку?***
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это ответ от разработчика библиотеки Wizou. [Оригинальный ответ тут.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72198289/c-sharp-wtelegramclient-telegram-api-how-to-programmatically-click-a-button-in-a/72228923#72228923) Выражаю ему большую признательность за потраченное время и точно указанную инструкцию по решению проблемы.  Это код действительно "нажимает на кнопку".

```
if (replyInlineMarkup.rows[2].buttons[0] is KeyboardButtonCallback btnCallback)
    {
        var answer = await _client.Messages_GetBotCallbackAnswer(peerBot, 
        tLMessage.id, data: btnCallback.data);
    }
```