# Нажатие кнопок WTelegramClient

Tags: c#, .net, telegram, wtelegram

Задача: Нажать на кнопку "клиентом" из последнего сообщения бота

Вопрос по материалу отсюда:
[C# Telegram-API WTelegramClient Как программно нажать кнопку в сообщении от Телеграм-Бота?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1408668/c-telegram-api-wtelegramclient-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Откуда взялись цифры **1911124859**?

```
var contacts = await _client.Contacts_Search("@Search_bot", 20);
contacts.users.TryGetValue(1911124859, out peerBot));
```

Откуда взялось и что такое **state** в контексте

```
var differenceMessages = await _client.Updates_GetDifference(state.pts, state.date, state.qts);
```

И можно ли организовать все это дело проще, без **peerbot**  как с:

```
var contacts = await _client.Contacts_Search("@Search_bot", 20);
contacts.users.TryGetValue(1911124859, out peerBot));
var message = await _client.SendMessageAsync(peerBot, "REQUEST");
```

=>

```
var resolve = await Client.Contacts_ResolveUsername("BOTID");
await Client.SendMessageAsync(resolve, "TEXT");
```